# how to implement custom Boost hash function for __uint128_t?

Tags: c++, boost, hash, 64-bit

How can I implement a hash function for a __uint128_t type that is compatible with Boost?

I tried this:

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_set>

#ifdef USE_64
typedef uint64_t MyId; // works fine
#else
typedef __uint128_t MyId;
#endif

inline std::size_t hash_value (const MyId x)
{
    // not a very good hash function, but I just want to get it working first!
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(x);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::unordered_set<MyId, boost::hash<MyId>> s;
    s.insert(42);
}
```

but I get 144 lines of errors (!) using g++-4.7.2 with Boost v1.51.0 on 64-bit Scientific Linux 6.2:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'hash_value(const __int128 unsigned&)'
```

Any guidance would be muchly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I have a feeling this is ADL problems. I don't know how boost hashing works but could you specialize something in boost's namespace instead?

Comment: Is the error only for __uint128_t even after the edit to your `#ifdef`?

Comment: Yes, using uint64_t works fine.

Comment: Did you try making the parameter a reference like it appears to be looking for based on the error message?

Comment: Yes, I tried making variable x a reference but it made no difference.

Comment: did you try adding the function to boost namespace? thought I think it is supposed to be done without that..

Comment: No, but it compiles fine when I use uint64_t, so clearly the compiler is able to find & use the custom hash function.

Comment: @ScottSmedley what makes you think that the compiler isn't finding and using *Boost's already existing `int64_t`* hash function? Don't inline yours. And use [`hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) to generate a hash from the two 64-bit halves.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out - I really appreciate it!

Comment: @vladr oh! I didn't think of that. Supposing the compiler chooses the default Boost implementation (for uint64_t) then I still have the problem of getting it to use my custom hash function - how do I do that?

Comment: @ScottSmedley the quick and dirty workaround is to declare `MyId` as follows: `struct MyId { __uint128_t value_; template< typename T > MyId(const T& value) : value_(value) {} bool operator==(const MyId& other) const { return other.value_ == value_; } operator __uint128_t() const { return value_; } };`

Comment: whoah! I'm impressed! Unfortunately for me, this is a simplified example of what I want to use a 128-bit integer for (I'm actually using a multi-index container from Boost). So ... any more ideas Big Brain!? :)

Comment: Add `operator<` for `MyId` so you can use it in both ordered and unordered containers.